# Only letter e is allowed in HTML5 tag?

Tags: html

Okay Just being geek! I have found something strange.
In HTML5 when we write this tag:

```
<input type="number" min="2" max="5"/> Number Only
```

So technically, it won't allow to use letters. But Strange part is it allows letter "e" to be typed in rather than any other letters.
Why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` is allowed as part of [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), so that when you need to write a large number, you can do it concisely.

Try inputting `2.4e5` and then hitting the up or down arrows.

```html
<label>
  Enter a number:
  <input type="number" min="1" max="1000000000"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Why are you posting an answer that repeats mine? If you want to add an example you can edit the existing answer...

Comment: @Amit, I posted an answer because I felt that I could provide additional detail that yours was lacking. Competition is good as it encourages quality.

Comment: Collaboration encourages quality. Competition encourages rivalry and fragmented answers.

Comment: @misterManSam, "you should all delete your answers" no, that's not how duplication works. Leaving the answers is fine, just be sure to vote to close the exact duplicate.

Comment: @zzzzBov - you're probably right, and I usually look for dupes when the answer is "long enough". In this case it was simply quicker to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because of exponent notation: 1.25E+3

Comment: Okay but how it works can you show me any link or something like that?

Comment: @JayminsFakeAccount - how what works?